# jquery submit only works once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to jquery but can't get the following to work properly. I can submit my form only once, after that i can't submit it a second time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#register').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        type: $(this).attr('method'), 
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#regrespons').html(response); 
            $("#regrespons").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#regrespons").fadeOut(1000); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>

<form id="register" action="includes/register.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input class="inp" name="gebr`enter code here`" type="text" />
<input class="inp" name="ww1" type="password" />
<input class="inp" name="ww2" type="password" />
<input class="inp" name="mail" type="text" />
<input class="but" type="submit" value="Registreren" />
</form>
```

Any help is apriciated!

Comment: why do you fade out #regrespons on success?

Comment: Can I see the HTML that includes `#regrespons`?

Comment: You need to give us more information - the code you posted is working fine in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBKKJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `$("#register").submit(function () {` to `$(document).on('submit', '#register', function () {`

Comment: @Kolink I'm actually not 100% sure that this is the solution; I don't see `#regrespons` in the HTML, so I need to see the full HTML.  It's possible that the form is not surrounded by `#regrespons` after all

Comment: Is your form contained by the `#regrespons` element? If that's the case, when you replace the content of `#regrespons`, the old form element is gone and the new form element won't have any submit handler attached to it.